# Programmatically added <br>-element to text inside a span is not breaking the line

Tags: html, css, razor-pages, line-breaks

I use [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp) solution to add a tooltip to my webpage. The application is an MVC ASP.NET application with Razor pages. I want the text of the tooltip to have line breaks (`<br/>`). This can be done by adding the HTML `<br />` in the text. This works well, however, I have a function (see below) at the top of my page that renders a string that is added to my span-element with the `<br>`-tags.

```
 private static string GetEmployeeList(ProjectSchedule ps)
{
    if (ps.Employees.Count > 0)
    {
        string empList = string.Empty;
        foreach (var employee in ps.Employees)
        {
            empList += employee.Name + "<br/>";
        }
        return empList;
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

The result of the function is something like: `"Name 1<br/>Name 2<br/>Name 3<br/>"`.

The piece of code rendering the tooltip looks like:

```
 <div class="data-tooltip">
    Developers
    <span class="data-tooltiptext">@GetEmployeeList(item)</span>
 </div>
```

The problem is that the `<br/>` is not working, when the tooltips shows I see the hardcoded `<br/>` as part of the string while I expected the result looks something like: 
Name 1 
Name 2 
Name 3

The styling used:

```
.data-tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.data-tooltip .data-tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
    /* Fade in tooltip - takes 1 second to go from 0% to 100% opac: */
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;

}

.data-tooltip .data-tooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}

.data-tooltip:hover .data-tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Does someone have an idea how to solve this? TIA.

Comment: try replacing `</br>` with `\n` in the function `GetEmployeeList`

Comment: @ShashankGb thx for the reply, unfortunately, that doesn't work. There are no breaks visible in the tooltip. I also tried (since it is c#) Environment.NewLine. That doesn't work either.

Comment: The tooltip itself looks okay. It seems the problem is with the function.

Comment: How can `<br/>` is displayed in html page, According to my knowledge it's impossible.. Use developer options in browser and please post that screenshot of that tooltip. It will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have recognized the right problem in your answer, but that is not the correct solution. Your solution has the danger that if the names contain any HTML, that will be rendered as well, which opens you up to HTML and script injection attacks.

Generally you should avoid using `@Html.Raw` and shouldn't generate HTML outside the template. All HTML generation should instead happen directly in the template:

```
<div class="data-tooltip">
    Developers
    <span class="data-tooltiptext">
    @foreach (var employee in item.Employees)
        {@employee.Name<br/>}
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I haven't thought of that, this is a good and valid solution. I Have changed my code based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

After all, the solution was simple (as always).

@Shashank Gb got me thinking. First I used the developer tools, but there the outputted string showed ad "Name 1 `<br/>` Name 2`<br/>`"

So nothing wrong there I would say. However, when I used "View page-source" I saw that the `<br/>` was rendered to `&lt;br;&gt`

The solution for me was to use @Html.Raw, this prevented the conversion of the HTML `<br/>`-tag:

```
<div class="data-tooltip">
  Developers
  <span class="data-tooltiptext">@Html.Raw(@GetEmployeeList(item))</span>
</div>
```

Thx for the help.